# disable scroll of scrollbox (FMX, C++)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

Where can i find the list of possible values for TouchTracking on a TScrollBox?

```
ScrollBox->AniCalculations->TouchTracking = ??
```

I want to disable the scrollbox scrolling temporarily.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39765564/disable-the-scroll-temporarily-of-a-tvertscrollbox-component-in-delphi) shows for Delphi but i'm too inexperienced to know how to convert to C++.

Comment: For now i'm just doing `ScrollBox1->Enabled = False;`

Comment: *Where can I find ...* The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.InertialMovement.TAniCalculations.TouchTracking) should be the first place to look, no? I used the **index** and searched for *touchtracking*.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I just don't know the syntax.  `Form1->ScrollBox1->AniCalculations->TouchTracking = ttHorizontal;` doesn't work.

Comment: As `TTouchTracking` is a `set` type, use the set operators `<<` (to insert to the set) and `>>` (to exctract from the set)

Comment: Thanks Tom, I should have thought of that as Remy helped me last year with similar use of <<.  Obviously, i don't code for a living (just fun).  `ScrollBox1->AniCalculations->TouchTracking = TTouchTracking() << ttHorizontal;`

Answer (score 1):

From the designer select the scrollbox and then Touch -> Interactive gestures and untick Pan (from object inspector).